# Rails 3.1: Should File Uploads be added to asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have a rails 3.1 application that allows users to upload pictures. Should these pictures be stored as assets(in app/assets) and therefore be subject to Sprocket overhead(caching, fingerprinting, etc.)? Or should I keep them in public/images and store them outside of the asset pipeline?

Comment: The asset pipeline is for organizing your assets, not for serving user-uploaded content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The asset/image is IMHO for structural/design images (background, icons, banners etc).
Dynamically added pictures/assets should go in the public directory.

Comment: I've done that, but I keep getting `No route matches [GET] "/system/files/694/large/772.jpg"` even though the file actually exists on the filesystem under `/public`. Any idea how to fix this routing issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this trouble and it was a permissions problem.  If you are running under apache with the www-data user do this:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data public
sudo chmod g+rws public
```